# fPrintf an integer gives weird results

Tags: c, printf, cfprint

I am working on a C code where I need to do some debugging. That is why I am saving a value 'width' in a file.
The codes are:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
FILE* fp2;
fopen_s(&fp2, "test.txt", "w");

width = 0.05;

fprintf(fp2, " %d ", width);

fclose(fp2);
```

The code should print 0.05 in the file. But, it is printing -1717986918.

As I am saving the values in loop, in the file 0.05 should be saved until the loop runs, but -1717986918 is saved as the loop runs.

Can anyone help me?

`width` is a float variable.

Comment: please post a [mre] and don't tag c and c++ unless you are really using both, they are separate languages

Comment: Your `%d` says that the argument is an `int`, but it's not. Using the wrong format specification has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes! it is float. can you tell what it is then?

Comment: Read some documentation about format strings.

Comment: @molbdnilo, yes gotcha, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to output `width` as an integer with `%d`, which causes this kind of behavior. If you use `%f`, it will work properly.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for the insightful comment. I was basing my assumption off of the assignment of the variable, but I can see that there could be underlying issues, like the variable being set to int before assignment. Again, thanks for the insightful comment, as I'm new to answering questions, I have lots to learn.

Answer (score 0):

As you specify in comment your `width` variable is a float.
To fprint a float you need to use `%f` in this way:

```
fprintf(fp2, " %f ", width);
```

For more information about formatting of fprint you can see the following [reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm) or the [wikipedia page for printf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string)